# How to calculate algorithm's accuracy in cross validation and repeat cross validation

Tags: r, cross-validation, accuracy

I'm using R tool to make machine learning algorithms.
I made algorithm and now I have to evaluate model accuracy.
So I used train(), trainControl() function.
In trainControl() function, I used cv & repeatcv parameters to evaluate.

I am wondering that how to calculate model accuracy in cv & repeatcv.
Is it calculated mean of produced algorithms?? or Is the model with the highest accuracy selected?

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

In order to evaluate performance of a model, you split your data into train and test datasets, use cross-validation to test the model on the train data. In the regression setting, the most commonly-used measure of accuracy of the model is the mean squared error (MSE):
$$
MSE=1/n∑(y−f(xi))^2
$$
where $f(xi)$ is the prediction that you've got for $i$th observation.

For classification setting we compute error rate:
$$
1/n ∑I(yi \neq f(xi))
$$

There are other methods of accuracy measuring, you can easily google them.